# Unable to test j2me application on Java mobile

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I am developing a J2ME application using **Netbeans**. I am able to Run that app in **emulater** , but when I tried to copy .jar file in my java phone, it is not running, showing **Nullpointer Exception.**
Please help me.

Comment: Can you show me the code please ? and in which mobile you are testing it ?

Comment: One of the golden rules with JavaME: Never ever trust emulators. Always test as much as you can on a real device, or even better; many different real devices.
You can't expect anyone to be able to help you though, without posting the source code.

Comment: I am installing in nokia 2700 and my MIDP version is 2.0 and cldc version is 1.1....My code is so huge...In which part you are interested....Now it is giving out of memory error...

Comment: You can edit emulator settings, and give it less memory. Try doing that. Then you may be able to see the same errors on the emulator. When you do that, then try inserting System.out.println("Yes, reached line x"); here and there. That way you can slowly pinpoint where the problem occurs.
One possibility is that you're trying to load a huge image. When loading fails, all subsequent attempts to draw the image-object will give a NullPointer exception.

Comment: Thank you for your response.....could any one tell me how we can run application on mobile in debug mode using Netbeans tool.

Comment: In general, you can't debug on real devices (some makers and models have support though), but you could install the [Nokia S40 SDK](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Java/Tools/) and test on the most similar emulator you can find.

Answer (score 0):

Check your jad settings for midlet settings.Whether you specified correctly or missed any thing such as midlet name,etc